# Настройка онлайн тв-трансляции

Tags: html, трансляция

Как настроить онлайн тв-трансляцию для сайта с сайта http://www.videohlam.ru/tv канал 2x2 ?

Вот исходный код:

```
<div style=" display:block; width:683px; height:400px; " id="player" > </div><script> var fl = flowplayer( "player", {src: "http://www.videohlam.ru/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2..;, wmode: "opaque"},{plugins: {rtmp: {url: "http://www.videohlam.ru/swf/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf..;, netConnectionUrl: "rtmp://stream3.optizone.ru:1935/rtmp", durationFunc: "getStreamLength", }}, clip: {provider: "rtmp", scaling: "fit", autoPlay: "true", }, playlist: [{url: "/stream/vlc45.ts", }], key: "#$ed0988d801182c22a8f" , autoPlay: false, canvas: { backgroundColor: "#000000", backgroundGradient: "none", } }); </script>
```

А вот ссылка на трансляцию: `/stream/vlc45.ts`

В общем, получается запустить только сам плеер а трансляция никак не идёт... То есть получается, что ссылка трансляции то ли неполная, то ли ещё что... Возможно, нужно её как то дополнить, чтобы она заработала?

Comment: @Scandal, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.